# SQL query ordered alphabetically

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I have a table as below,

```
ID    Description
--------------------
1     Bacteria
2     Cell Lines
3     Compounds
4     Virus
5     Others
6     AntiBody
```

What I want is a single SQL query, ordered alphabetically but have 'Other' (ID 5) as the last record.
Is that even possible?

Any help would greatly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
SELECT ID, Description
    FROM YourTable
    ORDER BY CASE WHEN ID = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
             Description
```

Answer (score 10):

```
SELECT ID, Description
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY CASE WHEN Description = 'Others' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END, Description
```

Comment: Don't you think it would be more advisable to filter on ID?

Comment: @syneptody: Not particularly. Why do you think so? Personally I'm not a big fan of magic numbers in source code unless there's a very compelling reason. If you want a performance improvement you could fetch the ID of the row with the Description 'Others' and use that, but given that there are only 6 rows, it seems like overkill to me (and maybe it would even be slower!). Anyway, the OP didn't really provide that much information about his specific needs so it's rather hard to say what's best.

Comment: Certainly a case-by-case call but in general 1) There is a stronger likelihood that ID will be covered in an index 2) There is a stronger likelihood that Description will change before ID does and 3) If you use ID (in this case) you could change which value you want to show up last without touching the query (just update description where ID = 5)

Comment: @Mark, Thank you for the answer. And you are right this table is never going to be more that 200 records so the efficiency/performance is not-a-big-deal.

Comment: @syneptody I don't know about 1) but I agree with 2) and 3), so I agree with using ID=5